# Ungestüm oder unbändig

Tags: difference, synonym

> **ungestüm**:  
>    1. seinem Temperament, seiner Erregung ohne jede Zurückhaltung Ausdruck gebend; stürmisch, wild 
>      2. (seltener) wild, heftig, unbändig
>
> **unbändig**:   
>  1. ungestüm, wild 
>      2. (von Gefühlen o. Ä.) durch nichts gedämpft, abgemildert, sich ohne Beschränkung äußernd; nicht zu zügeln; heftig

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ungestüm* bezeichnet meist ein *temperamentvolles*, *impulsives*, vielleicht jedoch weniger wildes Verhalten:

> Der Verteidiger unterbricht ungestüm den Vortrag des Zeugen.

Hier würde *unbändig* weniger passen.

*unbändig* wird eher im Sinne von *maßlos*, *grenzenlos* oder *riesig* im Zusammenhang mit Emotionen oder Eigenschaften verwendet:

> Ich freue mich unbändig.
>
> Der Sportler hat eine unbändige Ausdauer.

Diese Bedeutung hat *ungestüm* nicht. *unbändig* kann allerdings auch ein wildes, unkontrolliertes Verhalten beschreiben:

> Die Kinder toben unbändig herum.

Dabei sind *unbändig* und *ungestüm* oft austauschbar.

> Die Kinder toben ungestüm herum.

bedeutet im Grunde dasselbe.

Answer (score 7):

Wie die beiden Einträge erkennen lassen, gibt es offensichtlich einen Überlapp, wo beide Worte austauschbar sind. (*Seine unbändige/ungestüme Art wird nicht von jedem verstanden.*)
Zudem ist ungestüm das ältere der beiden.

Eine *ungestüme Umarmung* ist allerdings keine *unbändige Umarmung*, sondern vielleicht ein *unbändiges Verhalten*.
Die Beispiele [zu *ungestüm* hier](http://zwei.dwds.de/wb/ungest%C3%BCm) zeigen recht deutlich, wo man *unbändig* ersetzen dürfte.

In [diesem Eintrag zu *unbändig*](http://zwei.dwds.de/wb/unb%C3%A4ndig) gehören Begriffe wie *unbändiger/ungestümer Junge* oder *unbändig/ungestüm herumtollen* zum Überlappbereich, während ein *unbändiger Hunger* kein *ungestümer Hunger* sein kann.

Vermutlich und durch die Etymologie bestätigt bezieht sich *un-gestüm* auf das Gegenteil von Sanftmut und Ruhe. Dahingegen ist das Befreien von allen *Banden* Ausdruck eines Freiheits- oder Befreiungswillens, der mit *unbändig* in Verbindung gebracht wird.

**Man hat zum Beispiel ein *ungestümes Temperament*, aber ein *unbändiges Verlangen*, was den Bedeutungsunterschied recht gut beschreibt.**

*Ungestüm* ist oft eine Handlung, eine kurzer Zeitraum, während sich *Unbändigkeit* über einen längeren Zeitraum ausdrückt.

Answer (score -2):

ungestüm = hastig - unüberlegt agieren...

unbändig = überzogen und unkontrollierte Kräfte einsetzen...